# Как в jquery each получить следующий элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, разработка-игр

Мне нужно сравнить два элемента из массива, который выводится в `$.each()`. Как я могу сравнить эти два элемента? Или как я могу вывести конкретный элемент по индексу, как при работе с обычным массивом `arr[i] == arr[i+1]`?

Comment: можно тогда не через each, а взять посчитать кол-во элементов, и через for сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$.each()** используется для произведения циклический операций на объектами, массивами ([источник](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)). Одна итерация - одно свойство объекта/элемент массива.

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
    if(arr[index] == arr[index + 1]){
        //do some action
    }
});
```

И хоть такое использование **$.each()** и не вызовет ошибок (undefined на последней итерации), это не целевое использование функции.
Поэтому лучше для сравнения элементов массива в данном случае использовать цикл **for**

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1]){
        do some action
    };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо..........  .

Comment: Если решение вам помогло, отметьте ответ как принятый.